# localStorage onload show my selected div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how show hide div with localStorage, example if i select IT, onload show div IT.

my js code

```
itlang = document.getElementById('LangIT');         
itlang.onclick = function(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('a_avlang', '1');
        $('.avlan').hide();
        $('.av-it').show();
}; 
if (a_avlang === '1') {
    localStorage.getItem('a_avlang', '1');
    $('.avlan').hide();
    $('.av-it').show();
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('a_avlang', '0');
    $('.av-it').hide();
  }
}
```

my buttons html

```
<a class="avlangbuttons" href="#it" id="LangIT" target="_self">IT</a>
<a class="avlangbuttons" href="#en" id="LangEN" target="_self">EN</a>
```

My div to Show/hide html

```
<div class="avlan av-it" style="display:none;"> 
IT
</div>

<div class="avlan av-en"> 
EN
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invalid syntax.

1. `localStorage.getItem('a_avlang', '1');` is invalid, there is only one parameter on getItem
2. Why use getElementById and onclick when you have jQuery?

My guess is you mean

```js
function toggleAV(lang) {
  $('.av-it').toggle(lang=="LangIT");
  $('.av-en').toggle(lang=="LangEN");
  localStorage.setItem('a_avlang', lang); // saves LangEN or LangIT
}
$(function() { // onload 
  $('.avlangbuttons').on("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // stop the click
     toggleAV(this.id); 
  });
  toggleAV(localStorage.getItem('a_avlang') || "LangEN"); // if exists otherwise english
});
```

Alternatively use data-attributes instead of parsing the ID

Comment: Thank you very very mouch for your help.